# Javascript regular expression for complex string

Tags: javascript, regex

I want to create a regex which will match string like "123;qwe;12324", this regex is working fine:

```
[a-zA-Z0-9;]
```

But I want to allow blank spaces also if preceded or followed by ; but this is not working:

```
[a-zA-Z0-9;\s(?=;)]
```

Can someone please help.

Comment: You say "spaces", maybe you need `\s*` ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I guess

```
/^([a-zA-Z0-9]+\s*;\s*)*[a-zA-Z0-9]+$/
```

Test

```
> re.test('abc')
true
> re.test('abc;def')
true
> re.test('abc;  def')
true
> re.test('abc;  def;')
false
> re.test('abc^^^;  def;')
false
```

Comment: re.test('abc;  def;') should also be a valid string for me...please help

Comment: @JyotiPuri: try adding `;?` to the end